# Unexpected decimal value in MIPS console output

Tags: integer, mips

I used the following code to get 2 user inputs. But when integers are entered, an unexpected decimal value is given with the user input

```
.text

main:

la $a0, input_1
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $t1, $v0
syscall

la $a0, input_2
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $t2, $v0
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall


.data

input_1 : .asciiz "Enter integer 1\n\n"

input_2 : .asciiz "Enter integer 2\n\n"
```

The output on the console is

*Enter integer 1

1

268501062Enter integer 2

2

0.00000000*

Here 1 and 2 are the user inputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to call syscall after moving values between registers.Just delete the two syscalls right after the two move instructions. Here is the edited code.

```
 .text

main:

la $a0, input_1
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $t1, $v0


la $a0, input_2
li $v0, 4
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall

move $t2, $v0


li $v0, 10
syscall


.data

input_1 : .asciiz "Enter integer 1\n\n"

input_2 : .asciiz "Enter integer 2\n\n"
```